# Should REST API always return response with a message?

Tags: json, api, rest, server, backend

I'm not sure whether I should include success message in the response when I create an API server.
Like when you `PUT` something to the API server and the backend creates something successfully, you can get a response with 201 status code.
Does the API server should include a message like:

```
{
  "message": "Successfully created."
}
```

as JSON in the response?

Comment: not necessary,  it should return a meaningful response that you/your client can use on frontend

Comment: I suggest to use `@hapi/boom` library: https://hapi.dev/module/boom/api?v=9.1.4

Answer (score 1):

I agree with VoiceOfUnreason: it not is mandatory, but I usually return

```json
{"status":"ok"}
```

If I need to return some content

```json
{"status":"ok","result":{.....}}
```

And, in case an error occurs, I still prefer to return a 200 handling the error at the application level

```json
{"status":"ko","errorMessage":"Something went wrong!"}
```

Fabio

Answer (score 0):

> Should REST API always return response with a message?

It's not required - we have [204](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.3.5) (No Content) and [205](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.3.6) (Reset Content) in the standard because there are cases where a response without a body makes sense.

But in common cases where we are sending a 200/201, I would expect to see a response body describing [the status of the action](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-semantics#section-15.3.1)

> The 201 response content typically describes and links to the resource(s) created.

Answer (score 0):

No for example, for 204 responses we must not include message body. {success: true} is redundant.

In practice (or should I say in later version of jquery), empty response for application/json content type raises error. I kind of understand the argument that because it's application/json it must have a valid json body. So, empty response for application/json content type would be 'null' or '{}' which are valid json.

There's another way which should work for jquery, that is not returning application/json for empty responses. Just use text/plain or something and make sure client can handle that type.